# XML Serializer: Close Tag with attribute

Tags: java, android, xml, serialization

when the user starts my app for the first time, the app loads XML-Data from the web. However I don't want that the user needs to download the data every time he opens up the app. So I thought I save the data into a new XML-File that I generate with the data I just got. Then, the user gets a notification that the data he sees is loaded from cache and that he can click a button to sync the data and get the freshest data.

My problem now is, saving the data to the XML-File. I'm doing it with xmlSerializer and that works fine, except for one thing.

This is how I serialize some data:

```
xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "imageURL");
xmlSerializer.text(((Node) imageURLList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "imageURL");
```

The problem that I have now is that the XML I get is built up like this

```
root-element
     elementwithAttribute START
          data
     elementwithAttribute END
     elementwithAttribute START
          data
     elementwithAttribute END
root-element
```

The Attribute I have for the file is the number of the entry

```
entry nr="1"
```

I tried doing it like the following

```
xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "rank nr=\""+i+"\"");

data

xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "rank");
```

But this put me out of my for loop and only the first entry worked until the rank was closed improperly. When I close the tag like this

```
xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "rank nr=\""+i+"\"");
```

it works without problems, but then the XML file doesn't look like I want it to look like. How can I achieve it, that the serializer knows that `rank` is the end tag of `rank nr`?

Comment: The `nr="1` should be written as an **attribute** - just call `xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "nr", String.valueOf(i))` _after_ `xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "rank")`

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way how I now could read the file I saved? I'm writing everything to cacheSavings.xml - But I don't know where it gets saved. I think in the internal storage. I thought of uploading the file to a ftp-server of mine to check, but It doesn't work and I don't even get an Exception. Also my log doesn't work. When it doesn't succeed it should log, like here `if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                  else Log.v("upload result", "failed");` but it doesn't. do you know what could be the problem there?

Comment: You probably need to post more code to determine where it goes, if it's just for caching data you should probably be using `Context#openFileOutput("cacheSavings.xml")` or something similar - this can be retrieved by just calling `Context#openFileInput("cacheSavings.xml")`.

Comment: Hey, I'm dumber than I thought. I forgot that I have the whole data in a string, so I just printed it out via a TextView. And see: The whole XML is there! Thanks! :)